# Can a second rails application re-use an already purchased Redis instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Can a second rails application re-use an already purchased Redis instance?

In other words, is the Redis data namespaced by application name or some thing.

(somewhat related to [Get Two Rails apps to share the same Redis data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939394/get-two-rails-apps-to-share-the-same-redis-data))

Answer (score 1):

Redis normally includes 16 "databases" that are accessed by number.

```
redis://localhost:6379/0 # default
redis://localhost:6379/1
redis://localhost:6379/2
... up to /15
```

Set your redis configuration to a end in a different number and it will keep the data separate.

Comment: my env var REDISCLOUD_URL in heroku looks like redis://rediscloud:redacted@pub-redis-redacted.ec2.garantiadata.com:16227

Comment: I guess I can try adding a /1 to the end of the url

Comment: Right, you might need to check your provider's documentation on how to do that.